# Simple chrome extension logging to console not working

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Trying to write my first very simple chrome extension: it should write to console some message. Here is my code:

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name" : "Hello world",
    "version" : "1.0",
    "description" : "This is a simple chrome extention",
    "background": "background.html"
}
```

**background.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    window.onload = function() {
        window.setInterval( function() {
            console.log("Hello world");
        }, 10000);
    }
</script>
```

But it logs nothing into chrome console. What's wrong here?

Comment: Ok. changed to 'background_page' and get the following warning in chrome-extensions: "'background_page' requires manifest version of 1 or lower." . Anyway my typing wasn't 'random' but I'm afraid example I saw was deprecated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In modern Chrome it's better to use [event pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages) (nonpersistent background pages) and declare only the scripts.

- manifest.json:

  ```js
  "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"],
      "persistent": false
  },
  ```
- background.js:

  ```js
  window.setInterval( function() {
      console.log("Hello world");
  }, 10000);
  ```

  It prints in the [background page console](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10258029/3959875), not in a webpage console!

The only case when it makes sense to declare the html page is when you actually utilize DOM of the background page, for example for canvas.

Comment: Just figured out it with this link: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview Anyway thanks.